# Updating an object in an array causing same object updates everywhere

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an array that represents a list of dustbins to recycle different material and I can drop items into the correct bin to be recycled or into the "generic" bin. Every time I drop a new item, I want to update my array to include the new item in the correct box. Any item can be dropped in both "recycle" and "non-recycle" boxes.

My initial array:

```
const dustbins = [
         { 
           category: "generic", 
           type: "non-recycle",            
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "mj6548", type: "fruit", size: "s", container: 0},
            {id: "ki4689", type: "fish", size: "m", container: 0}
           ] 
         },
         { 
           category: "textile", 
           type: "recycle”,            
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "bg7548", type: "jacket", size: "s", container: 1},
            {id: "nh3695", type: "trousers", size: "m", container: 1}
           ] 
         },
         { 
           category: "metal", 
           type: "recycle",    
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "qw3215", type: "bar", size: "xs", container: 2},
            {id: "vf6523", type: "wheel", size: "m", container: 2}
           ]
         },
         { 
           category: "plastic", 
           type: "recycle",    
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "we6359", type: "board", size: "l", container: 3},
            {id: "dr6598", type: "box", size: "m", container: 3}
           ]
         },
]
```

Each item I drop is an object with the following format `{id: "bg7548", type: "jacket", size: "s"}`

The drop action calls a function that should:

1. Add the `container` property to the object with the value be the box I drop it into
2. Update the array to include the new item dropped into the appropriate box `droppedItems` property which is also an array.

My function

```
const handleDrop = (index, item) => {

// index represents the box I drop the item into and should be that value of the container
// an example of an item {id: "bg7548", type: "jacket", size: "s"}

// I add the container to the item object passed as parameter
item.container = index;

// I add the new item to my array inside the droppedItems of the correct box
dustbins[index].droppedItems.push(item);
}
```

The function works and updates the array however I have a problem when I drop an item that already exists in one of the boxes.

The item is added correctly to the appropriate `droppedItems` property of the correct box but the `container` value of that item in all boxes are updated to the last index passed.

Basically instead of just adding the new item, it also updates the `container` values in all the other boxes.

If for example, I drop the following item which already exists in the "generic" box `{id: "ki4689", type: "fish", size: "m"}` to the "plastic" container I get a new array as such:

```
const dustbins = [
         { 
           category: "generic", 
           type: "non-recycle",            
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "mj6548", type: "fruit", size: "s", container: 0},
            {id: "ki4689", type: "fish", size: "m", container: 3}
           ] 
         },
         { 
           category: "textile", 
           type: "recycle”,            
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "bg7548", type: "jacket", size: "s", container: 1},
            {id: "nh3695", type: "trousers", size: "m", container: 1}
           ] 
         },
         { 
           category: "metal", 
           type: "recycle",    
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "qw3215", type: "bar", size: "xs", container: 2},
            {id: "vf6523", type: "wheel", size: "m", container: 2}
           ]
         },
         { 
           category: "plastic", 
           type: "recycle",    
           droppedItems: [ 
            {id: "we6359", type: "board", size: "l", container: 3},
            {id: "dr6598", type: "box", size: "m", container: 3},
            {id: "ki4689", type: "fish", size: "m", container: 3},
           ]
         },
]
```

The new item has been correctly added to the "plastic" box, but the container value of the same item in the "generic" box has also changed from 0 to 3. I don't understand why that value changed since I only update a specific part of the array.

Apart from this issue the function works well.

Any idea how to avoid this?

Comment: Firstly, make sure you tag your question with the language you're using, that will help get the most eyes on your question. Your problem is that, `item` doesn't hold the literal object itself, it holds a reference/pointer to the object in memory. As a result, your index in `droppedItems` don't hold the actual objects themselves, but rather they hold references to your `item` objects in memory (as you're pushing a refernce when you use `.push(item)`). That means that when you update `item.container`, you're updating the one object in memory that both of your arrays are referring to.

Comment: To fix this, you can make a new object, so that it gets created as a new object in memory and thus has its own pointer/reference. To do that, you can create an empty object, and spread (`...`)/copy all of the (own enumerable) properties from your `item` object to the new object that you've created: `.push({...item, container: indx}); `

Comment: @Nick Parsons - Many thanks, all makes sense now and your suggestion works. Cheers!